# Unable to see installed packages in project interpreter - Pycharm

Tags: pycharm

I installed packages like pandas, numpy. But, when I navigated to project interpreter installed package is not displaying
And also Pycharm is not providing intellisense(In my .py file), Instead it is displaying bulb like icon to install respective library, And I installed from that too, still no intellisense(I hope library is not installed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check with `pip list` in the terminal to make sure. The problem sounds similar to [PY-29611](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-29611) problem (package installation fails but PyCharm reports success).

[2018.1.2 Release Candidate PyCharm build](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=23004355) should contain the fix, but you still have to figure out why the installation failed in the first place - try to install `pandas` from the terminal and check the error message if any.